# eigen values and eigen vector of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an n *n matrix all of whose entries are 1. Find all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$. I have checked for 2*2 ,3*3 matrices and guessing the answer but in general how to show.

Comment: They are all rank 1, and you can explicitly write the eigenvectors, right? Tell us more on what you think the answer should be and why.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**

- The dimension of the kernel of $A$ is $n-1$ (why?) so $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $n-1$;
- The last eigenvalue is determined by the trace (why?)
- For the eigenvectors solve the equation
  $$Ax=\lambda x$$
  for $\lambda$ the two founded eigenvalues.

Comment: +1 for that first hint... After a whole semester of a linear algebra class, I never had thought of that. :)